# Right click context menu with Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, dom-events, extjs5

### Problem description

I have prepared this index.html, which creates a simple **Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor**. I want to have a *right-click-context-menu*, which is capable of doing something with words that were marked by the user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <link id="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady( function(){

        var html_editor = Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

### What i have done so far:

I have tried to implement listeners and a contextmenu, but it doesnt show the menu when right-clicking, so at the end of the day my **index.html** looked like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <link id="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady( function(){

        var html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1 = Ext.create('Ext.Action', {
            text: 'html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1',
            handler: function(widget, event) {
                console.log("html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1 clicked!");
            }
        });
        var html_editor_right_click_menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            items: [html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1]
        });


        var html_editor = Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                viewConfig: {
                    listeners: {
                        containercontextmenu: function(view, e, eOpts) {
                            console.log("containercontextmenu listener");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

Unfortunately, neither a **console.log()** for the right-click nor a **right-click-menu** is showing up.
**Can someone point me in the right direction?**

### EDIT: (progress made)

I made a context menu appear using this code in index.html (the index.html is runnable for itself, if someone wants to copy&paste it), but i **can't get rid of the browsers-context-menu showing** inside the html_editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <link id="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady( function(){

        var html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1 = Ext.create('Ext.Action', {
            text: 'html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1',
            handler: function(widget, event) {
                console.log("html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1 clicked!");
            }
        });
        var html_editor_right_click_menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            items: [html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1]
        });


        var html_editor = Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()                 
            });

        html_editor.getEl().addListener('click', 
                                    html_editor_click_handler, 
                                    html_editor);
        function html_editor_click_handler(btn, e, eOpts){
            var clicked_button = btn.button;
            var click_x_pos = btn.pageX;
            var click_y_pos = btn.pageY;
            console.log(clicked_button + " " + click_x_pos + " " + click_y_pos);
            if(clicked_button == 2){
                html_editor_right_click_menu.showAt(click_x_pos,click_y_pos);
            }
        }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

**How to stop the browser-context-menu from appearing above the extjs5-context-menu?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the default context menu from showing up, call `event.preventDefault()`

However, there is an extra wrinkle in this case. The `HTMLEditor` creates an iframe which is used to do the editing.

You have to then set a `contextmenu` listener on the body of the iframe, after it has loaded. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ncn

You should not do what you were doing (handling the click and checking which button was clicked) because there are other ways to show the context menu. On the Mac, you can ctrl+click, on Windows you can use the context menu key on the keyboard.

```
var html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1 = Ext.create('Ext.Action', {
    text: 'html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1',
    handler: function(widget, event) {
        console.log("html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1 clicked!");
    }
});

var html_editor_right_click_menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    items: [html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1]
});

var html_editor = Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

// Find the iframe and wait until it's loaded
var iframe = html_editor.getEl().down('iframe', true);
iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // It's loaded, now set the context menu listener
    var body = iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
    body.addEventListener('contextmenu', html_editor_click_handler);
});

function html_editor_click_handler(e, iframe) {
    // Prevents the default context menu
    e.preventDefault();
    var click_x_pos = e.pageX;
    var click_y_pos = e.pageY;
    console.log("Context click " + click_x_pos + " " + click_y_pos);
    html_editor_right_click_menu.showAt(click_x_pos, click_y_pos);

}
```

Comment: It really helped me alot. There is another problem remaining though: When the text is long inside the html_editor-textfield, then a scrollbar appears. After scrolling down, the e.pageX and e.pageY positions point to the location inside the html_editor-textfield and the contextmenu is not appearing under the correct position, where the rightclick was made. To get the correct location i have tried: e.screenX - e.screenY, e.mozMovementX - e.mozMovementY, e.clientX - e.clientY. All do not place the contextmenu under the position of the rightclick. Have you any suggestions for that?

Comment: Another remaining problem: rightclick to open contextmenu, click on some entry, again rightclick to open contextmenu ----> the clicked entry is still highlighted. How to remove the highlight? I have tried by calling: html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1.setDisabled(true);html_editor_right_click_menu_action_1.setDisabled(false); but the highlight remains. I can open a new post if you want me to.

Comment: @kiltek Try calling `menu.focus();` after displaying it

Comment: I put `menu.focus()` into several places but it didn't work. Where to put it?

Comment: @kiltek Please create a new question so that it can be helpful to others. If you have an example as simple as the fiddle I created for you, it will make it that much easier to help.